# вставка блока внутрь иного блока

Tags: javascript

Имеется конструкция типа `<div id="show_chosen_address"></div>`, и нужно вставить внутрь блока `span`. Проблем с созданием спана, его класса и его содержимого нет, но вот когда я пытаюсь вставить спан в блок, то выходит `[object HTMLSpanElement]`(через *console.log(number_span)* выводит всё правильно, то что вставить собственно нужно).
Делаю так:

```
var div = document.getElementById('show_chosen_address'),
    number_span = d.createElement('span');

number_span.className = "number";
number_span.innerHTML = "test";
div.innerHTML = number_span;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

либо используйте [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), либо вставляйте [`number_span.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```js
var div = document.getElementById('show_chosen_address'),
  number_span = document.createElement('span');
number_span.className = "number";
number_span.innerHTML = "test";
div.innerHTML = number_span.outerHTML;

var div2 = document.getElementById('show_chosen_address2'),
  number_span2 = document.createElement('span');
number_span2.className = "number";
number_span2.innerHTML = "test2";
div2.appendChild(number_span2);
```

```css
#show_chosen_address,
#show_chosen_address2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="show_chosen_address"></div>
<div id="show_chosen_address2"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло) покопаю в документации описание методов